# SharePoint 2013 search alerts API in C#

Tags: development, 2013, search-results

I want to receive an immediate notification when query results are changed (new added documents, existing changed, documents deleted), i. e. monitor queries.

Is this possible to implement using C#. Is there an API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, you can only set Daily and Weekly Search Alerts. Since the content is crawled on a schedule, the alert would only trip after content is crawled. You can customize the process to a certain extent. I would start with this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161512(v=office.14).aspx it applies to 2010 but should not be much different in 2013.

There is an API that you can access if you wish to create and manage alerts. (The Alerts collection of the SPWeb object.) Here is a PowerShell utility that helps managed URLs after an upgrade: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/877d2abd-fce9-4545-b223-7637936dd888/